# Installing Chisel

Tags: ios

I'm trying to install Chisel.

I ran the following commands in command line.

```
brew update
brew install chisel
```

the final step is to follow the instructions that Homebrew displays to add chisel to your ~/.lldbinit.

I cannot find .lldbinit file. Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out. Simply create .lldbinit in your home directory. I used sublime and added the following text to the file.

```
# ~/.lldbinit
...
command script import /path/to/fblldb.py
```

make sure you update the 'path' portion with your actual path. This can be obtained from command line when you do 'brew install chisel'

Save, restart Xcode. Done!

Comment: If you solved your problem please mark your answer as accepted so others can see the solution easier

Comment: In my case the final path was:
/usr/local/opt/chisel/libexec/fblldb.py

Answer (score 1):

.lldbinit file is not required for lldb to work so it is not created by default. If you don't have it already just create new empty file and add all necessary lines to it.